# Git Unexpected Merge Result

Tags: git, branch

The last four commits in my repository look as follows.

As you can probably gather, I made a local change and a remote change (via Bitbucket edit of README).

I then tried to reconcile the two. I have not made any changes to README locally or so I thought.

After the merge, the changes to README are not showing. That is, it appears that Git retained the version of README that was present in the green "branch".

My question is two-fold: what did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: You can compare the changes (a diff) made by original readme.md commit `6a4623c` and the merge commit `2d4a4bd`, they should have the same changes

Comment: It'd be better if you could say how you did your merge. Plain `git merge origin/master` won't give these results, but since you don't even say what you're using it's kinda difficult to answer.

Comment: @jthill I was actually using something called magit. It is a mode for Emacs. I am not sure what it did behind the scenes. I did a pull, and it started a merge, which I then completed. :/

Comment: @Renat Commit `2d4a4bd` contains the version of README that was present in `c862748`

Comment: From the command line, run `git show -m 2d4a4bd` to get two separate diffs, of `2d4a4bd` vs each of its two parents. That will show you what your Emacs magit told Git to commit. It won't help with *why* Emacs-magit told Git that was what to commit, of course. :-)

Comment: As for fixing it, you have a bunch of choices: you could remove commit `2d4a4bd` entirely from your local branch with `git reset --hard HEAD^`, for instance, or edit the file, `git add`, and `git commit --amend` to shove `2d4a4bd` aside and replace it with a new and improved merge commit with a different snapshot, or you could just leave `2d4a4bd` in there and modify `README.md`, add, and commit again, perhaps by using `git cherry-pick` on `6a4623c`...

Comment: @torek Thanks. I did `git show -m 2d4a4bd`, as you suggested. It does look like Git was told to get rid of the wanted changes. It explains what we see, but not why.

Comment: @torek, I deleted the `2d4a4bd` locally. How would I proceed from there? I am not really fond of changing the file and recomitting again because formatting it (markdown) was a pain in the neck.

Comment: There's no need to make *changes* again but you do have to *resolve any conflicts* again (but this time, correctly). Run `git checkout master` to get on to commit `52785fe` again (`git log` should start from there at this point), then run `git merge origin/master` to merge again. If you got a merge conflict last time, you should get the same one again. Resolve it (correctly this time, using whatever merge tools and methods you like)—just make sure that the version you `git add` is the *correct* merged result. You can get that correct merged result from anywhere you like.